# How to import and use firebase exported database in mLab?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, firebase, mlab

I have currently exported my database from firebase. It looks like this:

```js
{
  "a" : {
    "-LH-wWiC6Pt874i" : {
      "OwnerUserId" : "in63Syuyuyighjj",
      "Passengers" : {
        "dUCMzvi5UIBd81jPRQhg2" : {
          "HasPaid" : false,
          "IsAccepted" : true
        }
      }
    },
    "-LHdt9z-RHmyEvQn" : {
      "OwnerUserId" : "7Gq0jhLhMhLgm1",
      "Passengers" : {
        "ZP049naZWDXy4mN6we33" : {
          "HasPaid" : false,
          "IsAccepted" : false
        },
        "hGC2YWQnUdMZdPCJLW43" : {
          "HasPaid" : false,
          "IsAccepted" : false
        }
      }
    },
    "-LIgKeiFlJE3LsI" : {
      "OwnerUserId" : "abcdef",
      "Passengers" : {
        "SGnMfEC3vf38lkzZJBqAD2" : {
          "HasPaid" : false,
          "IsAccepted" : true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "b" : {
    "-LHdt9z-RH27S0myEvQn" : {
      "DateTime" : "2018-10-30T03:16:50.000Z",
      "DropoffAddressDisplay" : "iiii",
      "DropoffAddressFull" : "Japan",
      "DropoffCity" : "hhhh",
      "DropoffCoordinates" : {
        "Latitude" : 44.43,
        "Longitude" : -90.541687
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

I want to import it to mLab, is there any quick way to import it and After importing it to mLab, I want to access it by a local node-mongo setup in my local system. Also, I don't understand why a key like this "-LH-wWiC6Pt874i" is added to each object and how would I access values for like "OwnerUserId" as it is some random number.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in mLabs to Import database in various forms:

We have four tabs when we login : Collections, Users, Stats, Backups and Tools.

Go to **Tools tab**. In import/export:

We have options to Import as Biary or JSON or CSV.

Copy the commands and use it to export or import